# How to close a MessageDlg without closing the form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a form on which I have a combobox with three values: 90, 95 and 99.  I want the user to choose from these three only and raise an error if another value is entered.  So I have written the following code to display a message alerting the user to the mistake.  The trouble is when the messageDlg appears and the user hits "OK", the entire form closes.  I want the user to be able to make the correct selection after he closes the MessageDlg.

```
        if not ((cbPILimits.Text = '90') or
                     (cbPILimits.Text = '95') or
                     (cbPILimits.Text = '99')) then
        begin
          MessageDlg('The PI limit levels can only be 90%, ' +
                     '95% or 99%.  Please choose among these three.',
                     mtError, [mbOK], 0);
          if not (TryStrToFloat(cbPILimits.Text, PIPercent)) then exit;
        end;

        Close;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form closes because you have `Close;` at the end of sample code, which will always execute, no matter if `MessageDlg()` is executed or not.

I assume you want to close form only if user selected valid value, otherwise show message and not close the form. You need to have something like this:

```
    if (not cbPILimits.Text = '90') or
       (not cbPILimits.Text = '95') or
       (not cbPILimits.Text = '99') then
    begin
      MessageDlg('The PI limit levels can only be 90%, ' +
                 '95% or 99%.  Please choose among these three.',
                 mtError, [mbOK], 0);

      // whats the point of line below? seems like obsolete
      if (not TryStrToFloat(cbPILimits.Text, PIPercent)) then Exit;
    end
    else
      Close;
```

Also, if you don't want to allow user to manually enter values into `TComboBox`, you can set `TComboBox.Style` property to `csDropDownList` to disable editing the value.

Comment: there is much more to the code in this procedure and and so I could not code the "Close" the way you have shown.  However, your second option is more appropriate in my case.  I did not know about the csDropDownList.  That did it.  Thanks.

Comment: The last line was to read the text from cbPILimits to PIPercent along with error checking.  But I guess you are right - if the user is restricted to only the three values in the list, it seems redundant to have an error check there.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have three distinct values, then it is better to use radiobuttons than a combobox - the user is constrained to those values. Then you don't need your dubious code regarding the messagebox.

I wouldn't handle the error checking this way. If your dialog box has an 'OK' button, then add the error checking to the OKBtnOnPress event; if there is a problem then set modalresult to 0. This means that the dialog box won't close even though the OK btn has been pressed.

You can display your error message on a status bar.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  If the messageDlg box does not close even when the OK button has been pressed, how does that take care of my problem?  Also, although using radio buttons would also solve the problem of restricting the user, I already have too many objects on my form and did not want to clutter it too much.

Comment: @user1505202: Don't use messagedlg to display a warning message. Your dialog box (which contains the combobox and other controls) has an OK button - check that all values are ok in the 'onPress' event. If there is a wrong value, don't close your dialog box.

Comment: I have a form that has a number of objects including the combobox in question.  I am not sure which dialog box you are referring to since it is not the messageDlg.  I was doing the validation when the Save (save the options on the form, that is) button was clicked.  However, it was closing the form without allowing the user to amend the value.  I think I understand what you are suggesting, but I think I was already doing that - by means of the onClick event of the Save button.  It was closing the form, though.  Hence my question.  Thanks.

Comment: I finally followed what you meant :-)  It really helped in another part of my code.  Thanks very much!